# Рассчитать количество дней, месяцев и лет между указанными датами. Для Java 7 и без Joda time

Tags: java, дата

Как рассчитать количество дней, месяцев и лет между указанными датами? Проблема в том что это нужно для Java 7 и нельзя использовать Joda time. Нужно учитывать высокосные года.

Comment: перевести в unix time можно? Если да, вычесть из одного значения другое - вот вам и количество секунд между датами. Остальное - простые арифметические вычисления

Comment: @kami а не могли бы Вы привести пример? я новичок в программировании

Comment: У вас есть два объекта Date. У каждого из них есть метод https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime() , возвращающий количество миллисекунд. далее - в соответствии с первым сообщением, с уточнением - не секунды, а миллисекунды. Всё остальное, включая високосные года учтётся автоматически.

Comment: @kami ну не совсем простые вычисления, все путают високосные года, ситуация усложняется тем, что каждые 100 лет високосные годы не происходят. А с месяцами еще сложнее...

Answer (score 0):

```
  Calendar calEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
  calEnd.set(2021, 3, 21, 20, 04, 04); //21 апреля 21 года 20:04:04

  Calendar calStart = Calendar.getInstance();
  calStart.set(2001, 4, 1, 9, 00, 00); //1 мая 2001 года, 9 утра
  
  int years = calEnd.get(Calendar.YEAR) - calStart.get(Calendar.YEAR); //разница в годах
  long millis = (calEnd.getTimeInMillis() - calStart.getTimeInMillis()); //разница в миллисекундах
  
  int days = (int )(millis/(24*60*60*1000)); //разница в днях
  int months = years*12 + (calEnd.get(Calendar.MONTH) - calStart.get(Calendar.MONTH)); //по-моему так
  
  System.out.println("years="+years+", days="+days+", months="+months);
```

Comment: вроде для "с 31 декабря 2000 года по 1 января 2001 года" выдаст разницу в 1 год, а должно быть - 1 день. Не думаю, что это соответствует постановке вопроса.